# How do I setup my Node.js server so clients can connect?

Tags: node.js, ip, host

My little node.js server works fine, but only the host machine is able to connect with it. When i try to connect with other clients (which are connected to the same router as the host), I don't get a response. The server is listening at port 3000 (also tried 80, no difference), I tried setting the host ip to the network ip of the host computer, 127.0.0.1 and left it empty, but nothing worked.
 How do i configure my server so that clients other than the host may connect?

Comment: This is really a network routing problem, it might need a lot more context. You need to get the router-assigned ip address; Usually something like `192.168.xxx.xx`. then just connect via your browser `http://192.168.xxx.xx:3000`

Comment: So do I need the ip of my router or the ip of my host machine in the local network?

Comment: The latter, you need the ip of your host machine on the local network. Of course if you're trying to deploy this outside your local network, there a several other steps, but if I'm reading your question right you want to just connect within your local network. Getting that ip can be accomplished a number of different ways depending on your platform. Assuming you are on a Mac or Linux (*nix) you can use this terminal command `ifconfig` and you should see a line somewhere like: `inet 192.168.x.xxx netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.x.xxx` that is your LAN address

Comment: Thats right, i want to connect over Wlan. I found my local address and hosted my server on 192.168.xxx.xx:3000,yet i cant reach the server. Not even with the host machine. Btw, this server is meant to receive and send html, if that is of any help.

Comment: When you're on the host machine, I assume you can access the website via browser at `http://127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: No. What's strange is that I cant even access the server when i put in 127.0.0.1 as the host ip, but i can connect when I leave the host ip blank and connect to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: What are you using to connect? A web browser? The answer to the original question is that you don't need anything else to connect to the node.js server other than the ip and port of the host. But we are now digressing into potentially code-level issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the listen IP to 0.0.0.0. This listens on every interface.
2. Turn off your firewall to check that it is not the issue. When you turn it back on, allow port 3000 TCP incoming and outgoing.

Comment: Turned out the problem was the host ip and the router firewall all along. Switched to ad-hoc connection between host and client and it worked like a charm on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

**127.0.0.1** is your local IP

if you are using wamp or mamp share your server on ip.

Next go on google check for **`whatsmyip`**. Give your ip adress to who you want to share your file.

> **Or if you consider to upload on server**

except node_modules you have to upload the necessary files and folders. In server try `npm install`.

Make sure you have `package.json`

If you are new to **Nodejs**. Try **Heroku**

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku

Comment: These are good initial steps for deployment – however I don't think the op is trying to deploy his code, just access it from his local network.